# Search by Managed Property - Not working for a few documents

Tags: search, kql, property, managed

On-premises SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Search Farm: for about 99.99% pdf documents (millions in the document library) search by Managed Property, **CustomDocumentId** (unique per doc), returns result. However, for a few, the similar query doesn't return results. Crawled history shows that document was crawled. Also, search by a different managed property like **ProviderNumber** finds the document. The property shows that it has a value. We can rule out the security as running queries as the Site Collection Administrator.

This works for most of the documents, but not for a few

```
CustomDocumentId:2E7AAA33-552E-A21B-14ED-11F423C14236
```

This returns the documents along with other documents

```
ProviderNumber:456734935983745
```

Comment: You probably already tried this, but does it make any difference if you add quotation marks around the document id? `CustomDocumentId:"2E7AAA33-552E-A21B-14ED-11F423C14236"`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but didn't work. Another piece of info is that we name the files GUID+File extension like 2E7AAA33-552E-A21B-14ED-11F423C14236.pdf and searching just for that finds the document. But that's not feasible as our SP is integrated with many business partners client applications, and we can't force them to update.

Comment: If you search for the doc in [SharePoint Query Tool](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool) you can check all the properties that has been captured for that item, maybe that will shed some light on the issue?

Comment: I have already compared all property values of a good doc with that of a bad doc, but didn't see anything unusual.

Comment: Have you trie `=` instead of `:` along with the quotes? The minus signs could be throwing things off. I second the opinion to use the Search Query Tool to help the troubleshooting.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Surprisingly, CustomDocumentId:2E7AAA33-* works. I have  able to reproduce the same in UAT with the same document. So, will be analyzing various logs and update you all about my findings. Yes, I will also use the SP Query Tool

Answer (score 0):

The issue was eventually resolved with some help from MS Support.

The underline cause: Managed Property' Metadata value for "**NoWordBreaker**" was set false

Solution: The metadata value was set to true

```
#Set NoWordBreaker to true
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity "CustomDocumentId" -NoWordBreaker $true
```